# Python pop() method not returning expected values from the list

Tags: python, list

I am just learning python and was trying to loop through a list and use pop() to remove all items from original list and add them to a new list formatted. Here is the code I use:

```
languages = ['russian', 'english', 'spanish', 'french', 'korean']
formatted_languages = []

for a in languages:
    formatted_languages.append(languages.pop().title())

print(formatted_languages)
```

The result is this :
`['Korean', 'French', 'Spanish']`

I do not understand why do I only get 3 out of 5 items in the list returned. Can someone please explain?

Thank you,
Ruslan

Comment: You’re modifying the list while iterating over it: that’s doomed to exactly the sort of problem you’re seeing. Iterate over a copy of the list by e.g. `for a in list(languages:` and then you need to pop from the correct list,

Comment: You could also use `for a in languages.copy()`.

Comment: But `languages .pop()` always removes the last element of the list so isn’t correct. Probably need to incrementally create a new list from the elements that aren’t popped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look:

```
languages = ['russian', 'english', 'spanish', 'french', 'korean']
formatted_languages = []

for a in languages:
    print(a)
    print(languages)
    formatted_languages.append(languages.pop().title())
    
    print(formatted_languages)
```

Notice what "a" is:

```
russian
['russian', 'english', 'spanish', 'french', 'korean']
['Korean']
english
['russian', 'english', 'spanish', 'french']
['Korean', 'French']
spanish
['russian', 'english', 'spanish']
['Korean', 'French', 'Spanish']
```

So A is moving ahead and then it cannot continue in the loop

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is changing the size of the list whilst the list is being processed, so that once you've got to spanish in the list (3rd item), you've removed french and korean already, so once you've removed spanish, there are no items left to loop through. You can use the code below to get around this.

```py
languages = ['russian', 'english', 'spanish', 'french', 'korean']
formatted_languages = []

for a in len(range(languages)):
    formatted_languages.append(languages.pop().title())

print(formatted_languages)
```

This iterates through the length of the list instead, which is only calculated once and therefore doesn't change

Comment: This throws an error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. Was able to solve by making a copy of a list for a in languages.copy()

Comment: Sorry, I just realised I made a mistake in the answer, I'll fix it now - It needs to be `len(range(language))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't get the full values is because you are making the list shorter on each iteration.

Consider what is happening in your loop:

```
for a in languages:
    formatted_languages.append(languages.pop().title())
```

By the time `a` is equal to the 3rd element in your list, you already removed 3 elements from it(including the current value of `a`), so the loop cant get next value from the list and ends.

If all you need to do is to capitalize all the strings in the list,
you can just do:

```
formatted_languages = [entry.title() for entry in languages]
```

You can also set the original list to `[entry.title() for entry in languages]` since you are popping the values from it anyway:

```
languages = [entry.title() for entry in languages]
```

If you prefer to use a for loop similar to what you have, you should utilize the `a` value in your loop:

```
for a in languages:
    formatted_languages.append(a.title())
```

I will point out that some of the comments and answers here suggested to make a copy of the list.

While this will work, it is not optimal since you waste memory by doing this and if the list is very large that might be impactful.